# Need to take image of docker image or container from application installed machine in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ansible-2.x

As i am working on docker, i need help to take a container or image from existing AWS box. In my AWS box our application is installed and initiated.

For our application initialization, it takes more time. So i want to deploy this container(application installed) while the box launching time itself. When i am taking docker container it will have my application initiated, as per my understanding. So i can save the application initialization time.

I am launching the machine through ansible in AWS VPC. So i can call the docker container there.

Can anyone help on this how to do this activity.

With Thanks,
Ezhilmurugan M I

Comment: Not sure what you mean by take image, do you mean commit changes in the container to save them, or download a copy of the container from the server, or something else?

Comment: Hi Ken, You are correct. What and all changes i have done after fresh OS. That i need to save to as a container and download for new servers in future.

Comment: So you have a container running on a server, there are changes in the container, and you want to save those changes so you can run on another server?

Comment: Yes. Exactly you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you `docker commit` your changes into an image with a tag, you can then push to a registry, and then pull down the images on another server.

```
$ docker commit <hash or name> yourusername/red_panda
$ docker push yourusername/red_panda
```

On other host

```
$ docker pull yourusername/red_panda
```

You could also export the image, transfer however you want, and then import the image on the new server.

```
$ docker export red_panda > latest.tar
$ cat latest.tgz | docker import - exampleimagelocal:new
```

Comment: Do I need to stop the running container before docker commit?

Comment: No, you do not need to stop the container to run a commit on it.